# Is there an Objective-C equivalent for JavaScript's ||

Tags: objective-c

In JavaScript, the || operator will return the first non-false-evaluating operand.  For example:

```
var x = null;
var y = "yup";
var z = x || y; // z is now "yup"
```

Is there an Objective-C equivalent for this?

For example:

```
NSString *x = nil;
NSString *y = @"yup";
NSString *z = x ... y; // z should now be @"yup", if "..." were an operator
```

Please Note:  The '||' does short-circuit in JavaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a compiler extension to C (and therefore ObjC) that does what you want:

z = x ?: y;

(for a standard C/ObjC version: z = x ? x : y)

Comment: Yes, THANKS!  It even does short circuit...  Thus the following code:  int x = 1, y = 10, z = (++x) ?: (++y); // x is now 2, y is 10, z is 2